# Where else can my IP be blocked besides iptables?

Tags: networking, security, ip

I executed the following code block in my remote machine after I wasn't able to ssh into it **from my permanent ip**:

```
(
sudo apt-get purge denyhosts
sudo apt-get purge fail2ban
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo sh /etc/csf/uninstall.sh
sudo apt-get install --reinstall openssh-server -y
sudo apt-get install --reinstall iptables -y
sudo iptables -F.
sudo reboot
)
```

Yet, I still can't ssh to my remote machine from my permanent ip (in contrast to ports 21 and 22, port 80 is open for my permanent ip and I can access my websites and PHPmyadmin through it without problem).

**Note: I can ssh my remote machine without problem from other ip address.**

I assume that my personal permanent ip is partially blocked in my remote machine (at least for ports 21 and 22), but I don't know where it is blocked. The code block includes reinstalling of iptables (and I even tried to fully remove it via `apt-get purge iptables`) but still I am partially blocked.

My question is where else my ip could be restricted or blocked, besides iptables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some other areas to look at in the SSHD configuration itself (usually `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`), in TCPWrappers (usually `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny`), and to ensure the SSH daemon is actually running. This is not an exhaustive list, but is the next things I would check were I in this situation.

Comment: Indeed, the source of my particular problem was in `/etc/hosts.deny`. Thanks and I thumbed up!